# Git remove commit without removing merge commit

Tags: git

I have this:

```
*   ea626d4 (HEAD -> main) Merging
|\
| * 27069d1 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) 
* | 5b02356 
|/
* 8978bec
```

I want to remove commit 5b02356 but preserve commit ea626d4

```
* ea626d4 (HEAD -> main) Merging, maybe with changed name
|
* 27069d1 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) 
|
* 8978bec
```

How can I do it? I tried `git rebase -i 8978bec`, but it removes last commit,

Comment: If you remove 5b02356 there's nothing to merge.

Comment: Do you want to remove 5b02356 but preserve its merged contents? Or are you trying to preserve the ID ea626d4?

Comment: Problem was, that when I rebased and droped commit 5b02356 it also dropped ea626d4, and I wanted to avoid this.  
Yes I wanted to preserve content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git reset --soft 27069d1
git commit
```

With `--soft`, the `reset` command jumps back to the given commit, but without changing the working directory, and leaving the files that differed between the two commits marked as "to be committed". The new commit will have the same content as the original one, but will be a regular non-merge commit.

Note that it is not actually possible to modify a commit in any way (changing its content, message, author, timestamp, parent(s), whether it's a merge, etc.) - whenever git lets you "modify" a commit, it's actually creating a *new* commit with a different SHA (and typically dropping the reference to the original commit, so it looks like you made an in-place modification). So your resulting non-merge commit will have a different SHA; there is no way to make the change you want and retain the commit SHA `ea626d4`.

Comment: Thank you it is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: This can also be done with `git revert 5b02356`

Comment: But I needed to remove it from history

Comment: @Schwern: True, though that complicates rather than simplifies the commit history (which may or may not be a good thing, but seemingly not what OP wants), and it might give merge conflicts if the original merge commit had conflicts. `reset --soft` should always work.

Comment: “without also changing its SHA” No, you can’t change that either. Commits are immutable, basically. The commit with a different SHA is a different commit.

Comment: @matt: True; I didn't phrase that too well. Improved the wording.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to remove commit 5b02356 but preserve commit ea626d4

If you remove 5b02356 there's no need for a merge.

```
*   ea626d4 (HEAD -> main) Merging
|\
| * 27069d1 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) 
| | 
|/
* 8978bec
```

It might as well be...

```
* 27069d1 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) 
|
|
* 8978bec
```

You can force an empty merge with `git merge --no-ff` and that is useful to retain "feature bubbles"; indications that work was done in a branch.